# Electron.js Как запретить растягивать окно?

Tags: javascript, electron

У меня есть приложение, и я не хочу чтобы пользователь имел право растягивать окно. Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 470,
    height: 180,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
      devTools: false,
    },
  });
  mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false)


  if (MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL);
  } else {
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, `../renderer/${MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_NAME}/index.html`));
  }
  
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете добавить в опции окна `resizable: false`:

```js
 const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 470,
    height: 180,
    resizable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
      devTools: false,
    },
  });
  mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false)


  if (MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL);
  } else {
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, `../renderer/${MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_NAME}/index.html`));
  }
  
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};
```

Так же можете ознакомиться с большим количеством опций в документации [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions).